# How to start Sidekiq Web UI on public 0.0.0.0?

Tags: sidekiq, rack, puma, sidekiq-monitor

In order to start sidekiq web UI I currently do:

```
rackup sidekiq_web.ru -p 9293
```

However once puma starts it listens only to `localhost`.

```
* Listening on tcp://localhost:9293
```

How can I run this on `http://0.0.0.0:9293`?

Thanks

Comment: Yes I do. I just want to run this on the server so I can access it from my local machine.

Comment: it says it is "Listening on tcp://localhost:9293". So you can run it from http://localhost:9293 , right?

Comment: Yes I can. But I can't access it from the outside world a.k.a my local machine.

Comment: I mean, no browser will ever show you a web page if you enter `http://0.0.0.0:9293` into the address field

Comment: True but if puma listens on 0.0.0.0 (that is all interfaces), once I type my server's IP `http://MY_SERVER_IP:9293` it will.

Comment: a quick google search said that you can add `-o 0.0.0.0` to the command line (after the -p). Does it work?

Comment: Yes it did! Thanks! I was probably searching for the wrong thing. For the record, what did you search for? (plz post your last comment as an answer so that I can accept it)

Comment: I searched "rackup listen on all interfaces". For me, the second result was [this site](http://www.jamesrobertson.eu/clf/2014/dec/25/running-rack-on-host-0-0-0-0.html).

Comment: Nice! Thanks. Thought it was a sidekiq issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-o` option.

```
rackup sidekiq_web.ru -p 9293 -o 0.0.0.0
```

This will make rackup listen on all available network interfaces.